# Using csv file name within text replace batch file

Tags: file, batch-file

My code below looks for the file "a.csv", replaces 123 with abc within the file, then saves it as "b.csv".

```
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion

(for /f "tokens=*" %%f in (a.csv) do if not "%%f"=="" (
        set "line=%%f"
        set "line=!line:123=abc!"
        echo(!line!
)) > b.csv

endlocal
```

I'm trying to get it to look for all the csv files in the directory, not just "a.csv", use the file name of the csv within the string replacement, and overwrite the file, not save it as a new one. So lets say I have this file structure:

```
Main Folder/
├── batchfile.bat
├── Folder1/
│   ├── 1.csv - contains "123"
├── Folder2/
│   ├── 2.csv - contains "123"
```

If I ran the batch file, I'd end up with this:

```
Main Folder/
├── batchfile.bat
├── Folder1/
│   ├── 1.csv - now contains "1"
├── Folder2/
│   ├── 2.csv - now contains "2"
```

So far I've tried this:

```
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion

(for /f "tokens=*" %%f in (*.csv) do if not "%%f"=="" (
        set "line=%%f"
        set "line=!line:123=abc!"
        echo(!line!
)) > a.csv

endlocal
```

I thought I could target all the csv's with *.csv, and overwrite the file by calling it the same thing as the original, but I'm having trouble getting it to work. I'm also really quite unsure how to get the file names of the csv's?

Example of the csv file I'm going to work with when it's working. This code will replace all the "REPLACE" text in here with the file name of the csv.

```
element_type,div_size,section_header_size,section_header_title,section_header_title_position,section_header_title_color,section_header_subtitle,section_header_subtitle_position,section_header_subtitle_color,section_divider_type,sections,sections_slides,sections_size,sections_uniqid,sections_style,sections_placement,sections_type,sections_class,sections_clogic,sections_logic,sections_internal_name,selectbox_internal_name,selectbox_header_size,selectbox_header_title,selectbox_header_title_position,selectbox_header_title_color,selectbox_header_subtitle,selectbox_header_subtitle_position,selectbox_header_subtitle_color,selectbox_divider_type,selectbox_enabled,selectbox_required,selectbox_text_before_price,selectbox_text_after_price,selectbox_price_type,selectbox_hide_amount,selectbox_quantity,selectbox_quantity_min,selectbox_quantity_max,selectbox_quantity_step,selectbox_quantity_default_value,selectbox_placeholder,selectbox_use_url,selectbox_changes_product_image,multiple_selectbox_options_default_value,multiple_selectbox_options_title,multiple_selectbox_options_image,multiple_selectbox_options_imagec,multiple_selectbox_options_imagep,multiple_selectbox_options_imagel,multiple_selectbox_options_value,multiple_selectbox_options_price,multiple_selectbox_options_sale_price,multiple_selectbox_options_price_type,multiple_selectbox_options_description,multiple_selectbox_options_url,selectbox_uniqid,selectbox_clogic,selectbox_logic,selectbox_class,selectbox_container_id,selectbox_include_tax_for_fee_price_type,selectbox_tax_class_for_fee_price_type,selectbox_hide_element_label_in_cart,selectbox_hide_element_value_in_cart,selectbox_hide_element_label_in_order,selectbox_hide_element_value_in_order,selectbox_hide_element_label_in_floatbox,selectbox_hide_element_value_in_floatbox
    "selectbox","w100","3","","","","","","","none","15","","w100","5b6a1572b89c01.49663444","","before","","","{""toggle"":""show"",""what"":""any"",""rules"":[]}","","Section","Framing Options","10","","","","","","","none","1","0","","","","","","","","","","","","","0","Fine Art Print|Framed Fine Art Print|Fine Art Canvas","||","||","||","||","Fine Art Print|Framed Fine Art Print|Fine Art Canvas","||","||","||","||","||","5b6a1572b89c75.54224467","{""element"":""5b6a1572b89c75.54224467"",""toggle"":""show"",""what"":""all"",""rules"":[{""section"":""5b6a1572b89c01.49663444"",""element"":""1"",""operator"":""is"",""value"":""Mounted""}]}","","","","","","","","","","",""
    "selectbox","w100",,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,"Fine Art Print Options","10","","","","","","","none","1","0","","","","","","","","","","","","custom","0","Mounted|Unmounted","|","|","URL/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/REPLACE-EEDBU-PRM.jpg|URL/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/REPLACE-EEDBU-PR.jpg","|","Mounted|Unmounted","|","|","|","|","|","5b6a1572b89c96.65721126","{""element"":""5b6a1572b89c96.65721126"",""toggle"":""show"",""what"":""all"",""rules"":[{""section"":""5b6a1572b89c01.49663444"",""element"":""0"",""operator"":""is"",""value"":""Fine%20Art%20Print""}]}","1","","","","","","","","","",""
    "selectbox","w100",,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,"Fine Art Print Sizes - Mounted","10","","","","","","","none","1","0","","","","","","","","","","","","","0","60 x 80 cm (24 x 32 in)|50 x 70 cm (20 x 28 in)|40 x 50 cm (16 x 20 in)|30 x 40 cm (12 x 16 in)","|||","|||","|||","|||","60 x 80 cm (24 x 32 in)|50 x 70 cm (20 x 28 in)|40 x 50 cm (16 x 20 in)|30 x 40 cm (12 x 16 in)","2222|222|22|2","|||","|||","|||","|||","5b6a1572b89ca4.24145542","{""element"":""5b6a1572b89ca4.24145542"",""toggle"":""show"",""what"":""all"",""rules"":[{""section"":""5b6a1572b89c01.49663444"",""element"":""0"",""operator"":""is"",""value"":""Fine%20Art%20Print""},{""section"":""5b6a1572b89c01.49663444"",""element"":""1"",""operator"":""is"",""value"":""Mounted""}]}","1","","","","","","","","","",""
    "selectbox","w100",,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,"Fine Art Print Sizes - Unmounted","10","","","","","","","none","1","0","","","","","","","","","","","","","0","60 x 80 cm (24 x 32 in)|50 x 70 cm (20 x 28 in)|40 x 50 cm (16 x 20 in)|30 x 40 cm (12 x 16 in)","|||","|||","|||","|||","60 x 80 cm (24 x 32 in)|50 x 70 cm (20 x 28 in)|40 x 50 cm (16 x 20 in)|30 x 40 cm (12 x 16 in)","1111|111|11|1","|||","|||","|||","|||","5b6a1572b89cc1.28559565","{""element"":""5b6a1572b89cc1.28559565"",""toggle"":""show"",""what"":""all"",""rules"":[{""section"":""5b6a1572b89c01.49663444"",""element"":""0"",""operator"":""is"",""value"":""Fine%20Art%20Print""},{""section"":""5b6a1572b89c01.49663444"",""element"":""1"",""operator"":""is"",""value"":""Unmounted""}]}","1","","","","","","","","","",""
    "selectbox","w100",,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,"Fine Art Canvas Sizes","10","","","","","","","none","1","0","","","","","","","","","","","","custom","0","60 x 80 cm (24 x 32 in)|50 x 70 cm (20 x 28 in)|40 x 50 cm (16 x 20 in)|30 x 40 cm (12 x 16 in)","|||","|||","URL/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/REPLACE-EEDBU-CA.jpg|URL/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/REPLACE-EEDBU-CA.jpg|URL/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/REPLACE-EEDBU-CA.jpg|URL/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/REPLACE-EEDBU-CA.jpg","|||","60 x 80 cm (24 x 32 in)|50 x 70 cm (20 x 28 in)|40 x 50 cm (16 x 20 in)|30 x 40 cm (12 x 16 in)","3333|333|33|3","|||","|||","|||","|||","5b6a1572b89ce0.42422459","{""element"":""5b6a1572b89ce0.42422459"",""toggle"":""show"",""what"":""all"",""rules"":[{""section"":""5b6a1572b89c01.49663444"",""element"":""0"",""operator"":""is"",""value"":""Fine%20Art%20Canvas""}]}","1","","","","","","","","","",""
    "selectbox","w100",,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,"Framed options","10","","","","","","","none","1","0","","","","","","","","","","","","","0","White Frame|Black Frame|Natural Frame","||","||","||","||","White Frame|Black Frame|Natural Frame","||","||","||","||","||","5b6a1572b89d00.69455004","{""element"":""5b6a1572b89d00.69455004"",""toggle"":""show"",""what"":""all"",""rules"":[{""section"":""5b6a1572b89c01.49663444"",""element"":""0"",""operator"":""is"",""value"":""Framed%20Fine%20Art%20Print""}]}","1","","","","","","","","","",""
    "selectbox","w100",,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,"White Frame","10","","","","","","","none","1","0","","","","","","","","","","","","custom","0","Mounted|Unmounted","|","|","URL/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/REPLACE-EEDBU-FRM-WH.jpg|URL/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/REPLACE-EEDBU-FR-WH.jpg","|","Mounted|Unmounted","|","|","|","|","|","5b6a1572b89d19.51579868","{""element"":""5b6a1572b89d19.51579868"",""toggle"":""show"",""what"":""all"",""rules"":[{""section"":""5b6a1572b89c01.49663444"",""element"":""5"",""operator"":""is"",""value"":""White%20Frame""}]}","1","","","","","","","","","",""
    "selectbox","w100",,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,"White Frame Sizes - Mounted","10","","","","","","","none","1","0","","","","","","","","","","","","","0","60 x 80 cm (24 x 32 in)|50 x 70 cm (20 x 28 in)|40 x 50 cm (16 x 20 in)|30 x 40 cm (12 x 16 in)","|||","|||","|||","|||","60 x 80 cm (24 x 32 in)|50 x 70 cm (20 x 28 in)|40 x 50 cm (16 x 20 in)|30 x 40 cm (12 x 16 in)","5555|555|55|5","|||","|||","|||","|||","5b6a1572b89d35.77353810","{""element"":""5b6a1572b89d35.77353810"",""toggle"":""show"",""what"":""all"",""rules"":[{""section"":""5b6a1572b89c01.49663444"",""element"":""5"",""operator"":""is"",""value"":""White%20Frame""},{""section"":""5b6a1572b89c01.49663444"",""element"":""6"",""operator"":""is"",""value"":""Mounted""}]}","1","","","","","","","","","",""
    "selectbox","w100",,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,"White Frame Sizes - Unmounted","10","","","","","","","none","1","0","","","","","","","","","","","","","0","60 x 80 cm (24 x 32 in)|50 x 70 cm (20 x 28 in)|40 x 50 cm (16 x 20 in)|30 x 40 cm (12 x 16 in)","|||","|||","|||","|||","60 x 80 cm (24 x 32 in)|50 x 70 cm (20 x 28 in)|40 x 50 cm (16 x 20 in)|30 x 40 cm (12 x 16 in)","4444|444|44|4","|||","|||","|||","|||","5b6a1572b89d53.22331786","{""element"":""5b6a1572b89d53.22331786"",""toggle"":""show"",""what"":""all"",""rules"":[{""section"":""5b6a1572b89c01.49663444"",""element"":""5"",""operator"":""is"",""value"":""White%20Frame""},{""section"":""5b6a1572b89c01.49663444"",""element"":""6"",""operator"":""is"",""value"":""Unmounted""}]}","1","","","","","","","","","",""
    "selectbox","w100",,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,"Black Frame","10","","","","","","","none","1","0","","","","","","","","","","","","custom","0","Mounted|Unmounted","|","|","URL/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/REPLACE-EEDBU-FRM-BL.jpg|URL/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/REPLACE-EEDBU-FR-BL.jpg","|","Mounted|Unmounted","|","|","|","|","|","5b6a1572b89d68.62685492","{""element"":""5b6a1572b89d68.62685492"",""toggle"":""show"",""what"":""all"",""rules"":[{""section"":""5b6a1572b89c01.49663444"",""element"":""5"",""operator"":""is"",""value"":""Black%20Frame""}]}","1","","","","","","","","","",""
    "selectbox","w100",,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,"Black Frame Sizes - Mounted","10","","","","","","","none","1","0","","","","","","","","","","","","","0","60 x 80 cm (24 x 32 in)|50 x 70 cm (20 x 28 in)|40 x 50 cm (16 x 20 in)|30 x 40 cm (12 x 16 in)","|||","|||","|||","|||","60 x 80 cm (24 x 32 in)|50 x 70 cm (20 x 28 in)|40 x 50 cm (16 x 20 in)|30 x 40 cm (12 x 16 in)","8888|888|88|8","|||","|||","|||","|||","5b6a1572b89d75.66420811","{""element"":""5b6a1572b89d75.66420811"",""toggle"":""show"",""what"":""all"",""rules"":[{""section"":""5b6a1572b89c01.49663444"",""element"":""5"",""operator"":""is"",""value"":""Black%20Frame""},{""section"":""5b6a1572b89c01.49663444"",""element"":""9"",""operator"":""is"",""value"":""Mounted""}]}","1","","","","","","","","","",""
    "selectbox","w100",,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,"Black Frame Sizes - Unmounted","10","","","","","","","none","1","0","","","","","","","","","","","","","0","60 x 80 cm (24 x 32 in)|50 x 70 cm (20 x 28 in)|40 x 50 cm (16 x 20 in)|30 x 40 cm (12 x 16 in)","|||","|||","|||","|||","60 x 80 cm (24 x 32 in)|50 x 70 cm (20 x 28 in)|40 x 50 cm (16 x 20 in)|30 x 40 cm (12 x 16 in)","7777|777|77|7","|||","|||","|||","|||","5b6a1572b89d98.29842294","{""element"":""5b6a1572b89d98.29842294"",""toggle"":""show"",""what"":""all"",""rules"":[{""section"":""5b6a1572b89c01.49663444"",""element"":""5"",""operator"":""is"",""value"":""Black%20Frame""},{""section"":""5b6a1572b89c01.49663444"",""element"":""9"",""operator"":""is"",""value"":""Unmounted""}]}","1","","","","","","","","","",""
    "selectbox","w100",,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,"Natural Frame","10","","","","","","","none","1","0","","","","","","","","","","","","custom","0","Mounted|Unmounted","|","|","URL/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/REPLACE-EEDBU-FRM-NA.jpg|URL/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/REPLACE-EEDBU-FR-NA.jpg","|","Mounted|Unmounted","|","|","|","|","|","5b6a1572b89da7.45321633","{""element"":""5b6a1572b89da7.45321633"",""toggle"":""show"",""what"":""all"",""rules"":[{""section"":""5b6a1572b89c01.49663444"",""element"":""5"",""operator"":""is"",""value"":""Natural%20Frame""}]}","1","","","","","","","","","",""
    "selectbox","w100",,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,"Black Frame Sizes - Mounted","10","","","","","","","none","1","0","","","","","","","","","","","","","0","60 x 80 cm (24 x 32 in)|50 x 70 cm (20 x 28 in)|40 x 50 cm (16 x 20 in)|30 x 40 cm (12 x 16 in)","|||","|||","|||","|||","60 x 80 cm (24 x 32 in)|50 x 70 cm (20 x 28 in)|40 x 50 cm (16 x 20 in)|30 x 40 cm (12 x 16 in)","1111|111|11|1","|||","|||","|||","|||","5b6a1572b89dc7.71345110","{""element"":""5b6a1572b89dc7.71345110"",""toggle"":""show"",""what"":""all"",""rules"":[{""section"":""5b6a1572b89c01.49663444"",""element"":""5"",""operator"":""is"",""value"":""Natural%20Frame""},{""section"":""5b6a1572b89c01.49663444"",""element"":""12"",""operator"":""is"",""value"":""Mounted""}]}","1","","","","","","","","","",""
    "selectbox","w100",,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,"Black Frame Sizes - Unmounted","10","","","","","","","none","1","0","","","","","","","","","","","","","0","60 x 80 cm (24 x 32 in)|50 x 70 cm (20 x 28 in)|40 x 50 cm (16 x 20 in)|30 x 40 cm (12 x 16 in)","|||","|||","|||","|||","60 x 80 cm (24 x 32 in)|50 x 70 cm (20 x 28 in)|40 x 50 cm (16 x 20 in)|30 x 40 cm (12 x 16 in)","9999|999|99|9","|||","|||","|||","|||","5b6a1572b89dd8.56141959","{""element"":""5b6a1572b89dd8.56141959"",""toggle"":""show"",""what"":""all"",""rules"":[{""section"":""5b6a1572b89c01.49663444"",""element"":""5"",""operator"":""is"",""value"":""Natural%20Frame""},{""section"":""5b6a1572b89c01.49663444"",""element"":""12"",""operator"":""is"",""value"":""Unmounted""}]}","1","","","","","","","","","",""
```

Comment: So the string to replace is a full cell value? if so, I'd change the replacement to `!line:,123,=,abc,!` to not match a field like `012345`. Anyway, to loop over multiple files, wrap a `for` loop around; to overwrite, do the replacement in a temporary file (e. g., add extension `.tmp` to current file name), then move the temp. file onto the original one using `move /Y`...

Comment: Thanks. The string to replace will be just something like "REPLACE" in my csv file, and that will be replaced with the name of the csv file.

Comment: I've got the overwrite working with your suggestion so thanks for that (edited code in main question), but this line you suggested `!line:,123,=,abc,!` doesn't work. Do you know how to make that line say         `set "line=!line:REPLACE=  *get the name of the csv file here*  !"`

Comment: Great, `ren`and `del` is also a way to replace the original file... You should provide a short example excerpt of the file contents... If you have a `for %%i in (*.csv) do ( ... )` loop wrapped around to loop through all `.csv` files, use `%%~ni` to get the pure name of the current file...

Comment: Okay great thanks, nearly working. I've added my new code to my question. Still a bit stuck on the for loop working properly.

Comment: The command `rename *.csv temp.tmp` needs to be changed to `ren "%%~i" temp.tmp`, and the part `> a.csv` must be changed to `> "%%~i"`, the rest should be fine. Thanks for adding a CSV sample, so it is clear that my suggestion `!line:,123,=,abc,!` cannot work, because the string to be replaced can occur everywhere. By the way, if you find a solution by yourself, you should still not append it to the question, but post an answer instead...

Comment: I was going to post the answer when it was all working, I didn't think I should make answers if it still wasn't working. But regarding the code, that worked great for files in the main directly, but it doesn't seem to work when there's a csv file in a subdirectory. I thought that /r would do it, but after I run this, in the subdirectory I get a blank csv file and "temp.tmp" still in there not deleted?

Comment: Ah, of course, the `for /F` loop needs to be changed to `for /F "usebackq tokens=*" %%f in ("%~dpitemp.tmp") do ( ... )` and the `del` command to `del "%~dpitemp.tmp"`, then it should work finally...

Comment: Hmmm, not working with that? I've posted the full code above (I know you said not to do it but I dont seem to be able to post blocks of code here propperly, but I'll edit the question and put the final code into an answer when it works.

Comment: Sorry, `%~dpi` should of course read `%%~dpi` (twice in the code)...

Comment: Still not working with that, i'm getting a blank csv file with that? I've updated the code above.

Comment: Typo: the opening parenthesis in front of `for /F` seems to have suddenly disappeared...

Comment: Ahh yes. Thanks a lot for the help, working great (:

Answer (score 1):

Huge thanks to aschipfl for the help, here's the final working code for anyone else looking for something similar.

```
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
for /R %%i in (*.csv) do (
ren "%%~i" temp.tmp
(for /F "usebackq tokens=*" %%f in ("%%~dpitemp.tmp") do (
        set "line=%%f"
        set "line=!line:123=%%~ni!"
        echo(!line!
)) > "%%~i"
del "%%~dpitemp.tmp"
)
endlocal
```